# how to use Tuckey to convert non-www urls to www url along with parameters?

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat6, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am using only Tomcat to host my web application and do not have apache web server along with it and I am using Tuckey to convert the non-www urls to www urls but how do I take care of the urls with parameters? Following is the code that I am using in case of non parameter based urls:

```
    <rule> 
<name>Domain Name Check</name> 
<condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.mydomain.com</condition> 
<from>^(.*)</from> 
<to type="redirect">http://www.mydomain.com$1</to>
</rule>
```

But what do we do for urls with dynamic parameters?

Answer (score 0):

you need to include **use-query-string="true"** in

```
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
  <rule> 
    <name>Domain Name Check</name> 
    <condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.example.com</condition> 
    <from>^(.*)</from> 
    <to type="redirect">http://www.example.com$1</to>
  </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```